# is it okay grant public read access to some objects in my Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I store profile pictures in the s3 bucket and I store the aws URL in my database. when I need the profile picture I set the URL in the database into image tag.for this I set s3 bucket policy as public for read access.is this is a good idea or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Not answering as an answer since this is my opinion alone, but that's probably fine so long as the object URLs are not guessable.

Comment: ok, .thanks for the opinion.aws keep show warning about the public policy that why i worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going around making a bucket publicly accessible is to:

- put all your image files under one 'folder'
- create a CloudFront Distribution that serves only from that folder
- only allow read access to the Identity that will be generated by the CF wizard

On the back end you should be able to infer the final location of the assets, as you should know the CF endpoint at this point.

Note: you should set the CF endpoint as an env var for your backend and not hardcode it.